# Server to server authentication basics

Tags: security

While I understand the various options available for server to server authentication between REST services, I could use some clarification on the security implications of each approach.

I want a service to verify that a request received does originate from a legitimate calling remote service. No interactive users involved, assume the request happens as the calling service starts up. The three approaches usually mentioned are:

1. Use a fake user account and authenticate the client against the existing auth system
2. Use a shared secret / API key and sign the request
3. Use a client certificate (verifying the server is not a priority) 3.

The part I am missing is that it seems that all three methods depend entirely on the calling service's host (the client in the call) not being compromised. In the first approach this would give away the fake user password, but in the two other approaches an attacker could obtain the shared secret or the client certificate and impersonate the calling server just as easily as with approach number 1... so in what respect are 2 & 3 considered more secure?

Comment: If the two servers are windows servers in the same/trusted domains then each machine has a computer account which (if running in an appropriate security context) would be passed between them automatically.

Comment: Off-topic: belongs on http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have edited the question to specify that the question is independent of any specific deployment, this is about securing communications between two REST services.

Answer (score 1):

If the host is compromised, the game is already over. You cannot hope to use network security techniques to provide guarantees about the end systems, that is not what they're meant for.  Consider passwords, for example. When a user types in a password, the guarantee you have is that the entity that entered the password knows the password, that's all. Designing to be secure against compromised hosts is like trying to build a password scheme that only authorizes you if you're the real person - you're expecting a guarantee that the mechanism is not built to provide.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the calling server is not compromised you might want to use TPM based verification of the calling server in case the machines have TPMs on them. Once it has been verified that it is not compromised any of the above 3 methods would be secure.(ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module)